# Removed mongod lock file do i need to create users again

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I accidently closed my mac terminal.due to which i needed to remove my mongod.lock file and then run db --repair
My question is do i need to create users again in my database or everything else will remain the same?

Comment: No. You don't need to create users again. The .lock file is created when the mongo service stopped unexpectedly. You can remove the lock file restart the service. Most of the case you don't need to run repair command, just deleting the lock file is enough

Comment: thanks.. add this as an answer

Comment: added @Sameer Shaikh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You don't need to create users again. The .lock file is created automatically once the service started and will not gets deleted when the mongo service stopped unexpectedly. You can remove the lock file restart the service. Most of the case you don't need to run repair command, just deleting the lock file is enough

Comment: Not quite correct. The lock file is created when MongoDB starts and not *removed* when it stops unexpectedly. This is a measure to prevent two instances of `mongod` accessing the same data file. You should update accordingly.